# Неясность с обратной позиционной проверкой

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пример кода здесь:
http://ideone.com/IUAwc5
В регулярном выражении Вы увидите две строки:

```
(?<!\\d(?:р|г|к)\\.)
# (?<!\\d[ргк]\\.)
```

По здравому смыслу они означают одно и то же, но стоит раскомментировать вторую и закомментировать первую, то в результате работы мы увидим, что перенос строк был сделан и после 101р. 50. 2020г. , то есть второе выражение не срабатывает.
И такое поведение я наблюдаю не только в PHP, но и в Python.
Есть ли этому разумное объяснение, или это какая-то магия?

Comment: А Вы словами можете написать, чего же Вы хотит-то? То есть, что же должно сопоставляться с образцом. А то в одной альтернативе группы -- `\\.` и куча  negative lookbehind assertions (которые должны бы стоять перед шаблоном, с которым сопоставляете, а не после).

Comment: @alexlz, запостил происходящее как баг сюда:  
http://bugs.exim.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1341
Здесь минимально работающий пример:  
http://ideone.com/fdOelO  
Вопрос скоро удалю, только сначала просьба: я постил описание бага с помощью google-переводчика. Оцените, пожалуйста, качество английского текста- нет ли там казусов каких, Хотя в примере все четко видно, но все же.

Comment: Описание бага не понял. Что касается http://ideone.com/fdOelO -- всё вроде нормально.

Comment: Добавил такую строчку в пример:  

    echo preg_replace("/$RE2/", $repl, $text); // fail, expected аг бГ вГ гг
Описание бага на русском:  

    Если negative lookahead содержит символьный класс с unicode символами и что-нибудь еще помимо этого, то совпадение не будет найдено.
(?<=\\s[абв]) для примера,
если будет только символьный класс (?<=[абв]), или соответствующая ему альтернатива (а|б|в), то совпадение будет найдено.

Comment: Нечаянно коммент @avp удалил вместо своего, простите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus) затмение нашло, увы. А если так (RTFM):

```
echo preg_replace("/$RE1/u", $repl, $text); // ok
echo preg_replace("/$RE2/u", $repl, $text); // fail, expected аг бГ вГ гг
echo preg_replace("/$RE3/u", $repl, $text); // ok
```

Comment: @alexlz, ну да, про **u** позабыл (((  
Стыд и срам (((  
Становится понятно почему так происходит, если представить, что любой символ русский это два символа ASCII